# Anyway to encrypt MotionModel data?

Tags: rubymotion

Is there anyway to encrypt data for MotionModel? I was looking at it and it looks like it writes to a file. I'm not sure what would be the best transparent way to encrypt the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replied to this on the list, but to put this where SO readers can see it: MotionModel does not include any encryption technology. It does, however, include `before_save` and `after_save` as well as `before_delete` and `after_delete` hooks. Encryption could be placed in the the `before_save` hook method. That leaves the small matter of decryption which would be user implemented as-needed for display.